# output variable value to new file

Tags: racket

Currently I have the following code:

```
(define (write host code) 
  (with-output-to-file host 
    (lambda () 
      (printf code))))

(let   ([myself (find-system-path 'run-file)]
        [test (substring myself 1 3)])
  (printf "~s\n" myself)
  (write "hello.txt" myself))
```

I'm trying to write the value of variable "myself". Sorry for being such a noob, I'm not a huge fan of functional languages.

the error:

```
printf: contract violation
  expected: string?
  given: #<path:C:\Program Files\Racket\DrRacket.exe>
```

So i'm assuming I have to convert the variable myself in to a string? I'm confused here, I only know OOP languages such as perl/python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't the `printf`:

```
> (printf "~s\n" (find-system-path 'run-file))
#<path:/Users/soegaard/racketgithub/racket/racket/bin/../DrRacket.app/Contents/MacOS/DrRacket>
```

The problem is `substring`. The `substring` function expects a string as input, and gives an error, when it gets a path.

You can let `printf` restrict the length of the output like this:

```
> (parameterize ([error-print-width 20])
    (printf "~.s\n" (find-system-path 'run-file)))
#<path:/Users/soe...
```

Note the dot in `~.s`.

But you can also convert the path to a string, and then use `substring`.

```
> (substring (~a (find-system-path 'run-file)) 0 20)
"/Users/soegaard/rack"
```